# In LWC JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array)) not working as expected

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, json, child-to-parent, parent-to-child

I have an LWC that calls the backend, which makes a callout and returns the response wrapped inside an inner wrapper class with `@AuraEnabled` member variables and this wrapped class's `@AuraEnabled public List<VehicleWrapper> vehicleWrappers` list gets displayed in `<lightning-datatable>`. I am receiving the data object in this format: [image]

But when I assign `data.vehicleWrappers (an array of objects)` to `this.vehicleHistory` (which is declared as `@track vehicleHistory = []`) and print, I get a proxy object. Even if I do: `this.vehicleHistory = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.vehicleWrappers));`, I get a proxy object.
**Shouldn't I simply get the array without being wrapped in a proxy?**

[image]

If I print using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.vehicleHistory));`, I get as expected, without proxy:
[image]

So I decided to do this: `this.vehicleHistory = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.vehicleHistory));` and print but I see the same proxyed array as in the 2nd image.

I pass the array `this.vehicleHistory` to a child component. If I pass by stringifying the array to the child component (I know that [Arrays are proxied when passed to child components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/security_array_proxy.html)), then parse it and assign it to itself, it works. But it becomes a proxy object if I do something like slicing the array.

Stringify to pass it to child component as

```
this.vehicleHistory = JSON.stringify(this.vehicleHistory);
```

in parent component's html file:

```
<c-paginator records={vehicleHistory} page-size="2" onpagination={handlePagination}></c-paginator>
```

In the child component `paginator`'s js file:

```
@api records;
@track recordsToDisplay;
this.records = JSON.parse(this.records);
```

slicing the array:

```
this.recordsToDisplay = this.records.slice(this.startingRecord, this.endingRecord);
```

I have to stringify `this.recordsToDisplay` and send it in the detail of a custom event to the parent component. But when I parse it again, instead of receiving normal array, I get a proxy object.

Even if I don't stringify and send directly to parent and do `this.vehicleHistory = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail.sliced));`, I still end up with a proxy object.
**Why `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail.sliced))` doesn't work here?**

So this workaround of stringifying,parsing and passing to and fro between the parent and child component doesn't work in the end.

Parent component's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Child component's xml:

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>53.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>false</isExposed>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

I feel like this should not be this indirect or complicated. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't I simply get the array without being wrapped in a proxy?

There's a number of variables involved here. If all your components have the same API version, are in the same namespace, the Apex method is `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)`, and you're using Lightning Web Security, then you might end up receiving a plain `Object`/`Array`; I forget if there are additional rules, these are just the ones I recall. If any of these are not true, you're most likely going to get a `Proxy`. If the variable is bound to any markup, it will also become a `Proxy` immediately.

However, I feel this may be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Simply put, the `Proxy` is transparent, meaning that the executing code can't tell the difference between an `Array` and a `Proxy` that wraps an `Array`. The `Proxy` is only there to enforce certain rules (e.g. `@api` variables are meant to be read-only). Whatever problem you're having, except possibly the annoyance of having to open `[[Target]]` to visually debug objects, the `Proxy` is not likely the problem.

Comment: The main problem I am facing is <lightning-datatable> doesnt render the values. In my example I have 2 vehicles, and the datatable displays 2 rows correctly but the columns are all empty as if it is trying to display 2 empty arrays. Therefore I thought it is not able to display because it needs arrays and not proxy.

Comment: @nSv23 Here's a [demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/AXixW0uPqDeLVtz89qZS/src/app.js?p=stories) that trivially proves that Proxy isn't the problem. As I said, Proxy is transparent to running code. If I had to guess, you may need to [flatten your data](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/jkz8zbW1wCrlzBsBM7iq/src/app.css?p=stories).

Comment: The reason why <lightning-datatable> doesn't render the values even though it shows the number of rows correctly is because I am using a wrapper class that implements `Comparable` interface because I need to sort data I receive from a callout. If I remove the `Comparable` interface it works. I tried your flatten data but doesn't work. Is there a way to make it work with `Comparable` interface